# How to Extending 'backgroundTimeRemaining' more time?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background-process, ios13

I wanna extend backgroundTimeRemaining more than 30 seconds 
and according to Apple

"The value is valid only after the app enters the background and has started at least one task using beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:) in the foreground.

System conditions may end background execution earlier, either by calling the expiration handler, or by terminating the app."

so I try to add and edit but it can't work

here's what I tried

```
//MARK:- BeginBackgroundTask
func registerBackgroundTask() {
  backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask { [weak self] in
    self?.endBackgroundTask()
    print(self!.beginTime)
  }

//TODO: Add new background time ex: 60 sec
var backgroundTimeRemaining: TimeInterval {
        get{
            return 60
        }
    }

assert(backgroundTask != .invalid)
} 

//MARK:- EndBackgroundTask
func endBackgroundTask() {
  print("Background task ended.")
  UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
  backgroundTask = .invalid
}
```

Comment: You can't do that. Your app has gone into the background; you are lucky to be given any CPU time at all. Some other app needs the CPU. Let go of it.

Comment: I'll check new apply features about BGTask it may be helped Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`backgroundTimeRemaining` is informational to your app. The app does not control how much time the system gives it. You can request some background time in order to finish up some user-requested action, and you may receive it, but you don't have any control over how much time. You will need to redesign to not require this.

The point of `beginBackgroundTask` is to mark finite-length activities that, if the app were to go into the background in the middle, it would be useful to get a few extra seconds to finish up. If, for example, you are starting background tasks in `willEnterBackground`, or you are not calling a balancing `endBackgroundTask` in a timely manner, you are probably misusing the system and the system will tend to not give you background time at all.

See [Advances in App Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707/) for Apple's latest guidance on background execution.

Answer (score 0):

You ***can't*** specify any background running time for your app, instead you choose when your app would be awake by system/ notification,
check [Choosing Background Strategies for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/choosing-background-strategies-for-your-app#Defer-Intensive-Work)